# Не могу запустить iptables на ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

При попытке сделать iptables-restore - получаю следующую ошибку:

```
'ptables-restore v1.6.0: iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter
```

Моя iptables:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Comment: [первая ссылка](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170060/110559)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin это я видел. Автор написал, мол, использовал \n вместо \r\n. А куда эти \r\n\ вставлять-то?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=dos2unix

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а можно мне, пожалуйста, помочь, а не ссылки кидать?

Comment: воспользуйтесь программой dos2unix. куча примеров — по ссылке.